AWS Step Functions vs SNS for Full stack Controller-Model(s) Lambda Functions
I'm building a full-stack application using AWS and I'm currently working on my backend services; I have a Controller lambda that will communicate to other Model lambdas such as a CognitoModel, RollsModel (random name), etc. After looking through multiple Stack Overflow posts and AWS blogs it seems that directly having my controller lambda communicate with the other model lambdas is not a good idea but rather to use a service such as SNS, SQS, or Step Functions. From my undersstanding SNS is for push based messaging services that can be used for lambda to lambda communications, SQS is somewhat similar, and Step Functions allow for specific steps and logical flows for Lambdas to follow based on the events. Also form my understanding I need to have subscribed services with the mediators between my lambdas so each lambda triggers when called upon such as controller lambda to model lambda or vice versa. However, I'm not completely familiar with these services and I'm hoping someone more experienced with AWS can give me an overview on the best service for me to implement in my use case.
Thank You!
I've read through multiple other posts and AWS blogs as well as articles, but I don't have enough experience or familiarity to determine the best service architecture for my use case.

It sounds like you may want to look into eventbridge to handle the event routing.
